# RoR: Devise and Profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profiles

I'm a complete Rails noob and I'm working on my first rails app.

I'd like each user to have a profile, separate from the `users` table, but linked by id. I did this alright in PHP before, but rails syntax is new. :/

How do I create a profile for each user when they register via devise? And how do I link their `users/edit` page to edit their profile instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read this tutorial about [Relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

It's really easy to declare associations in Rails.
In your `app/models/user.rb`, you could do something like that:

```
has_one :user_profile
```

Your **user's profile** is a different object with its own table. Just make sure that you had the foreign key **user_id** in it, and you're good to go (also, you should specify `belongs_to :user` in your user's profile model).

Now, using Devise, if you want to make sure that a profile is being created after a user registers, you could do something like that (still in your user's model):

```
after_create :create_child
# Creating child Elements
def create_child
  UserProfile.create("user_id" => id)
end
```

And then, if you want to 'link' a specific URL to a controller, see the [routing tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Hope it helps.